# Cannot store a number with f:convertNumber into a Map

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a strange situation where i the f:convertNumber doesnt work when trying to store it to a untyped Map.

I expect the number to be stored as a java.lang.Double object in the Map.

---

Here's the xhtml excerpt :

```
<h:inputText value="#{tInputBean.generalMap['myNumber']}" id="testNumber">
    <f:convertNumber />
</h:inputText>
<p:message for="testNumber" />
```

---

And here's the bean :

```
@Named("tInputBean")
@Scope("view")
public class TInputBean {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TInputBean.class);
    private Map generalMap = new HashMap();

    // .. and the setter getter
    ....
}
```

---

And here's my log :

```
DEBUG PhaseTracker - BEFORE PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
DEBUG PhaseTracker - AFTER PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
DEBUG PhaseTracker - BEFORE PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
DEBUG DebugUtil - ============== start debugMap parameter map : ==============
DEBUG DebugUtil - testNumber='123123123'
DEBUG DebugUtil - javax.faces.partial.execute='SaveHeader testNumberPanel RPBPanel'
DEBUG DebugUtil - SaveHeader='SaveHeader'
DEBUG DebugUtil - javax.faces.partial.render='messages RPBPanel DebugVersionHeader testNumberPanel'
DEBUG DebugUtil - javax.faces.source='SaveHeader'
DEBUG DebugUtil - j_idt42='j_idt42'
DEBUG DebugUtil - javax.faces.ViewState='7088371747667351331:-3641627426454744246'
DEBUG DebugUtil - transNum='TRX003'
DEBUG DebugUtil - javax.faces.partial.ajax='true'
DEBUG DebugUtil - ============== end debugMap parameter map : ==============
DEBUG PhaseTracker - AFTER PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
DEBUG PhaseTracker - BEFORE PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
DEBUG PhaseTracker - AFTER PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
DEBUG PhaseTracker - BEFORE PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
DEBUG PhaseTracker - AFTER PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

---

And after the render, `<p:message for="testNumber" />` is replaced with : `{0}: Conversion error occurred.`

---

The things i notice is :

1. There's no exception happening while the conversion error occurs. Nothing is handled by my exceptionhandler which captures and log all exceptions. No exception trace.
2. I cannot specify a type like java.lang.Double in the `<f:convertNumber>` tag.

---

Should i make my own converter for this to work ? Im already imagining things like :

```
<h:inputText value="#{tInputBean.generalMap['myNumber']}" id="testNumber">
    <f:converter type="MyDoubleConverter" />
</h:inputText>
<p:message for="testNumber" />
```

Please share your opinion on this matter.
Thank you !

---

UPDATE

---

I've built a simple converter that suits my need, and so far it's been working ok. Here's the code, please share your opinion on this :

```
@FacesConverter(value="Double")
public class DoubleConverter implements Converter {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DoubleConverter.class);

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        //log.debug("locale : " + context.getViewRoot().getLocale());
        DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(context.getViewRoot().getLocale());
        //log.debug("VALUE == " + value);
        String result = value == null || value.toString().trim().length() == 0 ? null : format.format(value);
        //log.debug("RESULT == " + value);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        //log.debug("locale : " + context.getViewRoot().getLocale());
        //log.debug("STRING VALUE == " + value);
        DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(context.getViewRoot().getLocale());
        try {
            Object result = ((value == null) || (value.trim().length() == 0)) ? null : format.parse(value).doubleValue();
            //log.debug("RESULT == " + result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e,e);
            throw new ConverterException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how my jsf make use of it :

```
<h:inputText value="#{tInputBean.generalMap['myNumber']}" 
   id="testNumber" converter="Double"/>
<p:message for="testNumber" />
```

Comment: @Cristian Boariu: Wow ! That works, thank you ! But i have another issue now : when being rendered inside the inputText, it'll have this **1.23123123E8**. This wouldnt happen with the f:convertNumber as it'll format based on the locale (if im not mistaken). Any suggestions on this matter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i made my own simple converter for this purpose, and the code has been posted at the bottom of the original post.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
<f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Double"/>
```

If you want to format you can use a converter for numbers:

```
<f:convertNumber type="number" maxIntegerDigits="3"/>
```

Details about number formatting you can find [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFPage7.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the idea. But i notice that f:converter tag doesnt support the **pattern** attribute. I tried your idea out, but it's still showing the **12.23123123E8**. Before this i tried out nesting **f:attribute name="pattern" value="....."** inside the **f:converter** tag hoping it to work, but failed also.

Comment: @Albert Kam - Your are right, pattern attribute exists for `f:convertNumber` only. Can you try with my updated answer?

Comment: Hello, i've updated my test also, using only f:convert, or only f:convertNumber, or even both combination nested inside that inputText. Only f:convert worked, but with no formatting. The rest failed with conversion error. Im currently trying out my own converter as well in the mean time.